# my simple onclick function is not working

Tags: javascript, validation, alert

I have used onclick function to check values. But it not returning javascript function.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_product" onclick="return check()" class="btn btn-default">Add Product</button>
```

I tried giving alert to test like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
alert("Hello");
return false;
}
</script>
```

But it always submitting the form without returning the function

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/cKNH4/)

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uaJcP/)

Comment: Any reason it's `return check()` rather than just `check()`? I don't use inline JS much.

Comment: I need to alert "hello" when I click on submit. But it does not work

Comment: you mean to say that the alert is not being invoked?

Comment: Also is there any other javascript/jquery function related to this submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `check()`, not `return check()`

Comment: I'm not sure it's that. If you look at @Quentin's example you can see it works with `return check()`.

Comment: Should give return check(). Otherwise it will submit the form after function. And also my issue solved. javascript was disabled in my browser. That was the issue. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Try with below statement:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_product" onclick="check()" class="btn btn-default">Add Product</button>
```

Just make your button execute the `check()` function instead of `return check()` on the click event.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that. If you look at @Quentin's example you can see it works with `return check()`.

Comment: Yes this is right and that can be related to browser though. So avoiding the return would make perhaps.
That was a wild guess and I'm interested in the possible solution or even the main cause.

Comment: Should give return check(). Otherwise it will submit the form after function. And also my issue solved. javascript was disabled in my browser. That was the issue. Sorry for that. Anyway thanks